# How to find next available time-slot for asset_type with multiple assets of type

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've got a table with reservations for my assets.
We have n-number of assets `$nof`, which can be reserved with increments of 15 minutes between an opening hour `$open` and closing hour `$closed`

If there aren't any assets available for a chosen point in time, I want to find the next available time where there is at least 1 asset available for 60 minutes.

I now iterate with increments of 15 minutes over the table to check for availability, and break out of the loop when `availability > 0` happened more then 4 times (4*15m) resetting it when `availability ==0`.

But this just feels not right. And besides it's slow :(

This is an example I distilled from my database. `asset_type` comes from another table which is linked on the `asset_id` in an `asset` table. For clarity i'm ommitting this join, and representing it as column.

```
Reservations
id   | asset_id | asset_type | start            | end              |
-----+----------+------------+------------------+------------------+ 
2    | 67       | 99         | 2017-01-16 11:00 | 2017-01-16 14:00 |
4    | 67       | 99         | 2017-01-16 14:30 | 2017-01-16 15:45 |
3    | 54       | 99         | 2017-01-16 12:30 | 2017-01-16 16:00 |
```

In total there are 2 assets of type 99 normally available: 67 and 54.

So:

```
// nextAvailable($assesTime, $gap_in_minutes, $nof_assets, $asset_type);

echo nextAvailable('2017-01-16 11:30', 60, 2, 99);
// 15:45, 
// not 14:00 as there is only 30 minutes between res#2 and #4
```

What would be the best approach to tackle this problem?

Comment: there will never be a "best" approach to any problem you might come across - there are *"slow"* and *"fast"* algorithms ... the amount of answers to your question literally is infinite, expect it to be closed or flooded with opinions

Comment: ... so then, technically, this is a table of assets that are **not** available - i.e. they're reserved between those time slots?

Comment: I don't get your question. You say that you are requesting 2 assets for 60 minutes, yet from 15:45 only one of them is available for 60 mins (67), however, the other one is not available. Yet you suggest that 15:45 should be returned as a result. Since you do not have enough assets available to satisfy the request, then why would 15:45 be returned?

Comment: @Shadow I'm only asking for at least 1 asset to be available. The number 2 is the total number of assets normally available.

Comment: @CD001 that's correct. The asset 67 is reserved from 11-14 and 14:30 till 15:45. So it's available at 9:00-11:00 and 14:00-14:30 and 15:45-18:00. The 9 and 18 are openinghours of the shop.

Comment: @specializt Best might be the wrong descriptor... I'm not asking for a complete code; but a fast(er) algoritm. Preferably as a sql-query and without to much unnecessary code :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, Lets make some data!

```
DECLARE @DateToCheck DATETIME = '2017-01-16 11:30'
DECLARE @LengthOfTimeInMinutes INT = 60
DECLARE @TimeSlotLengthInMinutes INT = 15

DECLARE @Reservations TABLE
(
    id INT,
    asset_id INT,
    asset_type INT,
    startdt DATETIME,
    enddt DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO @Reservations
( id, asset_id, asset_type, startdt, enddt )
VALUES
( 2, 67, 99, '2017-01-16 11:00', '2017-01-16 14:00' ),
( 4, 67, 99, '2017-01-16 14:30', '2017-01-16 15:45' ),
( 3, 54, 99, '2017-01-16 12:30', '2017-01-16 16:00' );
```

Now I'm going to make a numbers table to generate some 15 minute timeslots so we can see the slots that are filled and the ones still available

```
DECLARE @number_of_numbers INT = 672; --Total Number of TimeSlots to Generate at 15 Minutes, 4 per Hour, 96 per day, 672 per week

;WITH 
a AS (SELECT 1 AS i UNION ALL SELECT 1),
b AS (SELECT 1 AS i FROM a AS x, a AS y),
c AS (SELECT 1 AS i FROM b AS x, b AS y),
d AS (SELECT 1 AS i FROM c AS x, c AS y),
e AS (SELECT 1 AS i FROM d AS x, d AS y),
f AS (SELECT 1 AS i FROM e AS x, e AS y),
numbers AS 
(
    SELECT TOP(@number_of_numbers)
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS number
    FROM f
), Rooms AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT r.asset_id FROM @Reservations r
), TimeSlots AS
(
    SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, (n.number - 1) * @TimeSlotLengthInMinutes, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @DateToCheck), 0)) AS TimeSlot
    FROM numbers n
), RoomSlots AS
(
    SELECT r.asset_id, t.TimeSlot
    FROM TimeSlots t
    CROSS JOIN Rooms r
), Reserved AS
(
    SELECT rs.asset_id, rs.TimeSlot, r.id, r.startdt, r.enddt
    FROM RoomSlots rs
    LEFT JOIN @Reservations r
        ON r.asset_id = rs.asset_id
        AND rs.TimeSlot >= r.startdt AND rs.TimeSlot < r.enddt
), LookingForSlots AS
(
    SELECT st.asset_id, st.TimeSlot AS StartSlot, DATEADD(MINUTE, @LengthOfTimeInMinutes, st.TimeSlot) AS EndSlot
    FROM RoomSlots st
)
```

Now in the code above, I made a series of 15 minute timeslots for each of the available assets for the week I was checking - (roomslots) 
Then I joined the roomslots to the reserved assets to make an overall view of which timeslot per room was used/available.

Now lets look for some open spots:

```
    SELECT top 10 l.asset_id, l.StartSlot, l.EndSlot, r.*
    FROM LookingForSlots l
    LEFT JOIN Reserved r
        ON l.asset_id = r.asset_id
        AND l.StartSlot < r.enddt
        AND l.EndSlot > r.startdt
    WHERE r.id IS NULL
        AND l.StartSlot >= @DateToCheck
    ORDER BY l.StartSlot, l.asset_id
```

Here is the output:

```
asset_id    StartSlot   EndSlot asset_id    TimeSlot    id  startdt enddt
54  2017-01-16 11:30:00.000 2017-01-16 12:30:00.000 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
67  2017-01-16 15:45:00.000 2017-01-16 16:45:00.000 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
54  2017-01-16 16:00:00.000 2017-01-16 17:00:00.000 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
67  2017-01-16 16:00:00.000 2017-01-16 17:00:00.000 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
54  2017-01-16 16:15:00.000 2017-01-16 17:15:00.000 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
67  2017-01-16 16:15:00.000 2017-01-16 17:15:00.000 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
54  2017-01-16 16:30:00.000 2017-01-16 17:30:00.000 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
67  2017-01-16 16:30:00.000 2017-01-16 17:30:00.000 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
54  2017-01-16 16:45:00.000 2017-01-16 17:45:00.000 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
67  2017-01-16 16:45:00.000 2017-01-16 17:45:00.000 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Now you can see the first slot found was for asset_id 54 at 11:30, and the next available is for asset_id 67 at 15:45.

It runs fairly fast in a set based manner, you can adjust the speed depending on the number of rooms/timeslots being generated (I generated just a week of data, you can set it lower to just generate a day to look against if you have many more rooms.

Eek, sorry, I didn't realize MySQL up there, you can turn much of this into tables to do the same calculations (or if you have sql server or postgres, they understand ctes)